# Share image and text message with Wechat not working in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, wechat, socialshare

Hi I am trying to share an image URL and description with a wechat user using UIActivityController but it fails to share the image. I have tried with the following code:

```
 UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]   initWithActivityItems:@[@"TestMessage", [UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseImage"], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]] applicationActivities:nil];

 activityView.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, 
 UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint];

 [self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am getting output as shown in following image: [image]

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, the below code works for me.

Sorry, I do not have exact code in Objective C but thought this might also be helpful.

```
        let objectsToShare : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        //add title and description
        objectsToShare.addObject(titleToShare)
        objectsToShare.addObject(myWebsite)
        if(self.pageThumbImage.image != nil)
        {
            //here pageThumbImage is an UIImageView object
            objectsToShare.addObject(self.pageThumbImage.image!)
        }
        let activityVC = ActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
        //New Excluded Activities Code
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeMessage,
        UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```